# Magento error 1014 when submitting an invoice

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have a problem with my Magento installation. When I'm loged in to the backend and try to submit an invoice I get a Error 1014: Back-end: unspecified error
There's no stack trace at all. Also my errorlog says nothing. There a lots of entries saying: client denied by server configuration: `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml`

What can I do to debug this, I haven't got a clue where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The problem had to do with the multisafepay extension. 
When a transaction is in progress and not finished the backend generates an error. 
When a transaction is 'pending' the system sends mail to the client so they can still finish the transaction. When they do that the invoice is generated correct. It's just a loose end of the extension but not a big deal.

Thank you for the help, Abid Hussain

Answer (score 0):

See this url

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/270355/#t373760

**Or try it:**

I was facing the same problem.Problem is with Tax class.Please follow these step for debugging

- Create a new product “test” and set Tax Class= NONE
- Add this “test” product to cart and try to place order.
- If order is place then do check how you setup tax in Magento.

Comment: Hi Abid, thank you for your answer.
I created a product 'test' with a tax class 'none'.
I've ordered this product, but there's still a problem when I try to submit the invoice in the backend. There's not really a difference with a tax class.

Comment: you can clear your magento cache or disable after the try it.

Comment: Still the same problem. And it's only a problem when order status is 'pending'. For the rest everything seems to work fine. Is there a way to get some more errors maybe?

Comment: which ext you have install in backend?